Discriminant of a cubic equation source
Does anyone know a reliable source (like a book or academic reference) that supports the following statement about the discriminant of cubic functions?
$\Delta > 0$: All three roots are real and distinct. $\Delta = 0$: All three roots are real, with at least two of them being equal. $\Delta < 0$: One root is real, and two of the roots are complex.
I found this statement online but would like to reference a more trustworthy source. Thanks in advance!

@YvesDaoust Thank you! But maybe something more modern? Just an Algebra book with this result e.g.

@YvesDaoust I have institutional access and the paper supports the statement, thank you so much!
